# Sigma-algebra on random variables

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X,Y:(\Omega,\mathbb{F})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$ be two real-valued random variables.

Given the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X,Y)=\{X\in A, Y\in B \mid A \in \mathbb{B}, B \in \mathbb{B}\}$, would you always be able to say $(X \in C) \in \sigma(X,Y)$ for a set $C \in \mathbb{B}$.

My try where I use only measurability of random variables

$$
(X \in C) = \mathbb{F} \cap (X \in C) = (Y \in \mathbb{B}) \cap (X \in C) = (Y \in \mathbb{B}, X \in C) \in \sigma(X,Y)
$$

Answer (score 1):

First of all $\{X\in A, Y\in B|A\in \mathbb B, B\in \mathbb B\}R$ is not a sigma algebra. In order to get a sigma algebra you have to consider sets of the type $\{(X,Y)\in D\}$ where $D$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

To show that $X \in C$ is in $\sigma (X,Y)$ write it as $\{X \in C, Y \in \mathbb R\}$.